# Фиксированное положение section при прокуртке

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Имеется проблема с section'ом (находится в середине страницы, т.е. выше/ниже есть такие же блоки). Я хочу чтобы в тот момент, когда этот section виден на экране, он имел фиксированное положение. Но если я проскроллю 200px вверх/вниз, то он снова становился статичным.

P.S. Проблема в том, что если я делаю его позицию фиксированной, все верстка съезжает.

Пробовал сделать фиксированное положение с помощью javascript, но section начинает дергаться.

```js
const element = document.querySelector('.list-tools_ul');

let Visible = function (target) {
    // Все позиции элемента
    let targetPosition = {
            top: window.pageYOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().top,
            left: window.pageXOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().left,
            right: window.pageXOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().right,
            bottom: window.pageYOffset + target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom
        },
        // Получаем позиции окна
        windowPosition = {
            top: window.pageYOffset,
            left: window.pageXOffset,
            right: window.pageXOffset + document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            bottom: window.pageYOffset + document.documentElement.clientHeight
        };

    if (targetPosition.bottom > windowPosition.top && // Если позиция нижней части элемента больше позиции верхней чайти окна, то элемент виден сверху
        targetPosition.top < windowPosition.bottom && // Если позиция верхней части элемента меньше позиции нижней чайти окна, то элемент виден снизу
        targetPosition.right > windowPosition.left && // Если позиция правой стороны элемента больше позиции левой части окна, то элемент виден слева
        targetPosition.left < windowPosition.right &&
        (targetPosition.top+targetPosition.bottom)/2<=(windowPosition.top+windowPosition.bottom)/2) { // Если позиция левой стороны элемента меньше позиции правой чайти окна, то элемент виден справа
        // Если элемент полностью видно, то запускаем следующий код
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};

// Запускаем функцию при прокрутке страницы
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let answer=Visible (element);
    if (answer){
        window.addEventListener('scroll', onscrollFun);
        window.scroll(0,document.querySelector('.big-height-two').offsetTop);//фиксированное положение
    }
});



function onscrollFun(e) {
    let top = window.pageYOffset;
    let copyThisLength;
    if (lastScrollTop > top) {
        console.log('top');

    } else if (lastScrollTop < top) {
        itemsCount--;
        copyThisLength=-1;
        if (itemsCount >= 0) {
            copyThisLength = itemsCount;
            content[copyThisLength].style.opacity = 1;
        }
        while (copyThisLength < content.length - 1) {
            content[copyThisLength+1].style.top = `${parseInt(content[copyThisLength+1].style.top) + 8}%`;
            content[copyThisLength+1].style.fontSize=`${parseInt(getComputedStyle(content[copyThisLength+1]).fontSize)-4}px`;
            if (100-parseInt(content[copyThisLength+1].style.top)<30){
                content[copyThisLength+1].style.opacity -= .3;
            }
            copyThisLength++;
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = top;
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Не сильно понял задачу, но для того чтобы блоки не прыгали можете добавить маржин на высоту блока у ниже идущего или добавить пустой блок.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вместо принудительного скроллинга скриптом делать нужному блоку смещение с помощью изменения (скриптом же) css-свойства:

```
{transform:translateY(Npx);}
```

где N - количество пикселей, на которое ушел скроллинг контейнера